# Why does the paste function inside a subset select statement cause an invalid argument to unary operator error?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several columns which I need to drop which start with the same prefix, e.g. income_2018, income_2017, income 2016. What I wanted to do is specify a variable at the start of my code - current_year. When current_year is set to 2018, I'd want to drop that and the previous two years columns too (income_2018, income_2017, income 2016).

I used the subset, in conjunction with the paste function to negatively select the columns and remove them, but the paste is causing an "invalid argument to unary operator" error.

```
current_year = 2018
df<- subset(df,select =-c(paste("income_",current_year,sep = ""),paste("income_",current_year-1,sep = ""),paste("income_",current_year-2,sep = ""),paste("income_",current_year-3,sep = "")))
```

Error in -c(someothercol, someothercol2, someothercol3,  paste("income_",  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Just for clarity, the problem isn't `paste`, per se, it's that you can't use negative indexing in `subset` if you are specifying column with a character, rather than the bare column name. e.g. `-column` is allowed, but `-"column"` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `-`, we can use `setdiff`

```
subset(df, select = setdiff(names(df), nm1))
```

where

'nm1' is the column names created by `paste`

```
nm1 <- paste0("income_",  current_year - (0:3))
```